# Onion Architecture Design with multiple applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, onion-architecture

-Solution
--Domain
--Infrastructure
--Service
--WebAPIApplication
--ConsoleAplication

I am currently working on a project to create a WebAPI application with Onion Architecture. The above image is my current solution structure.

I have no issue creating the WebAPI application with the Onion Architecture design pattern, but when I need to add additional service like a console application, how should I do? Reference again to Service & Infrastructure? Or Is there any best practice in this? Or Is this the correct way to design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing Service and Infrastructure layers again is the correct way to go. The main idea is to reuse your business rules, so that both applications have consistent behaviour.
Depending on your circumstance, you may need to create different implementations in the infrastructure layer for the console application, and that is ok. For example your console application may need a simpler repository than the Web API.

Comment: Thanks of you reply, I am thinking the same just need to create a different implementation in infrastructure layer as Web API & console application behave differently.